# Sync Calendar and Contact between Outlook 365 (Desktop) and Web (OWA) without using Exchange

Tags: email, sync, exchange, outlook-web-access, microsoft-outlook-365

I am trying to sync my contacts and calendars between my local Outlook and Outlook Web. I have my local Outlook setup as a Pop3 Account. I am aware that this would be possible by changing the POP3 Account into an Exchange Account, but I do like to store my emails locally and so I don't want to go that route.

I have searched for hours and not found a solution. I do get the feeling that Windows is really wanting users to use everything in the cloud. (Same issue with Office 365, but that's a different story).
Is there any way to go about this?

Answer (score 1):

As I know, there seems no official method to achieve that, maybe you could try some third-party add-ins in Outlook to see if it could help.
[Calendar Tools for Outlook](https://www.slipstick.com/addins/calendar-tools-addins/calendar-tools-for-outlook/)

Personally, I would more willing to use Exchange email account and ***[Archive](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/archive-items-manually-ecf54f37-14d7-4ee3-a830-46a5c33274f6)*** emails which I need to local disk.

Comment: How is everything going now?